# Equal height divs with footer always at bottom of tallest div

Tags: css

I was wondering if this were possible, and if it is the best way to go about this:
[example image](http://moreheadplanetarium.org/redesign/images/column_example.jpg) (since I'm not allowed to post pics yet ^^)

So, not only does each column have to be of equal height, but each column also has its own individual footer.

I saw [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347366/div-at-bottom-of-window-and-adaptable-height-div) — how could I rework this technique to apply to the bottom of the divs and not the bottom of the window?

**Edit:** each column will have content that will constantly change and be of variable height.  I'm thinking I could just figure out the equal height columns first, then just absolute position a footer div within those columns.  Does its parent div then have to be `position: relative`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a nested div in each that has the same properties. So each outer div is the same size, and so do the inside div.

```
.outer
{
height:500px;
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}

.inner
{
height:30px;
width:100%;
margin-top:-470px;
}

<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>
```

Didn't test this; off the top of my head!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that each column will be of variable height depending on content. I should've explained the image, but the blue section represents text, the red bg represents white space (to make equal heights), and the brown represents the footer.

Comment: OK, so you're looking for sticky footer. Try these sites:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

P.S. - there are NO bulletproof sticky footer techniques I've seen so far.

Comment: Yes, it a sticky footer, but it's for the bottom of three divs of equal height, not the page itself.  Do the same techniques apply?

Comment: You could try. Normally it's just for a page footer, but I don't see why it couldn't be applied to 3 divs.