# HTML / CSS: How to make the content follow the footer?

Tags: css, layout, html, liquid-layout

My problem is that I need a footer which is always on the bottom, even if the page scrolls etc.. but I don't know how to make the content follow the footer.

Please see the example given, this is a very similar layout, I have a sidebar also, but you can see with firebug, or something like that, that the `body` div is not following the footer.

---

**Example:**
[Click for demo](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm)

Comment: What you said in your question and what you said in response to rockinthesixstring seems to be two different things. From your question above, it sounds like *in the source code* you want the content portion to follow the footer. In the response you gave, it sounds like you want the footer to stick to the bottom of the screen until the page reaches its end, and then follow the bottom of the content. So my question is, which of these, or some third option, are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could make it with`Javascript` + `CSS`.**

With CSS you could put the footer to the bottom of the page, and with javascript your could specify the height of the page and modify the height of your content.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the jQuery Sticky Footer found at http://css-tricks.com

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/
http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStickyFooter/

Comment: the content is still remains the same, the question is not about the footer, it's about the content part, I don't want to have empty area between the content and the footer.

Comment: then sorry I don't follow. If your footer is simply to be at the bottom of the content without sticking to the bottom of the page, then simply implement a footer div that comes after the content div... it shouldn't be that hard. The harder option is to always have the footer stuck to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I need both in the same time.

Comment: Both options are not possible. The footer will either follow the content by default. Or using some trickery like the sticky footers option, it'll always be stuck to the bottom of the body.

Comment: I disagree with Mr. Haynes. Using javascript, one can set it up to remain fixed at the bottom if content has *not* reached its end, and when it reaches its end, 'release' the footer to follow the content up the page. The coding would take a little bit of work, and I'm not sure it would add value (seems like leaving the footer stuck to the bottom of the screen would be fine), but then, that's not really my decision, but whoever is designing the site.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similiar question before, you might want to check it out:

[Div at bottom of window and adaptable height div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347366/div-at-bottom-of-window-and-adaptable-height-div/1347402#1347402)